# Unable to set _id on elasticsearch-hadoop

Tags: python-3.x, hadoop, elasticsearch, pyspark

I am trying to write from an rdd to elasticsearch (pyspark, python 3.5). 
I am capable of writing the body of the json correctly but elasticsearch instead of taking my _id, it creates it's own.

My code:

```
class Article:
    def __init__(self, title, text, text2):
        self.id_ = title
        self.text = text
        self.text2 = text2

if __name__ == '__main__':

    pt=_sc.parallelize([Article("rt", "ted", "ted2"),Article("rt2", "ted2", "ted22")])
        save=pt.map(lambda item:
        (item.id_,
            {
            'text' : item.text,
            'text2' : item.text2
            }
        ))

        es_write_conf = {
            "es.nodes": "localhost",
            "es.port": "9200",
            "es.resource": 'db/table1'
        }
        save.saveAsNewAPIHadoopFile(
            path='-',
            outputFormatClass="org.elasticsearch.hadoop.mr.EsOutputFormat",
            keyClass="org.apache.hadoop.io.NullWritable",
            valueClass="org.elasticsearch.hadoop.mr.LinkedMapWritable",
            conf=es_write_conf)
```

Program trace:
[link to the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/89FZI.png)

Answer (score 0):

This is a setting of the mapping to the index, u can find out in the official user guide.
The sample code like this:

```
curl -XPOST localhost:9200/test -d '{
    "settings" : {
        "number_of_shards" : 1,
        "number_of_replicas":0
    },
    "mappings" : {
        "test1" : {
            "_id":{"path":"mainkey"},
            "_source" : { "enabled" : false },
            "properties" : {
                "mainkey" : { "type" : "string", "index" : "not_analyzed" }
            }
        }
    }
}'
```